# Using generic collections in Silverlight user controls

Tags: silverlight, generics, user-controls

There is an interface:

```
public interface IFoo {
}
```

A Silverlight user control has a collection of `IFoo` instances:

```
public ObservableCollection<IFoo> Items { get; set; }
```

There is an abstract class that implements the interface:

```
abstract public class Foo : IFoo {}
```

And a class that further derives from that:

```
public class DerivedFoo : Foo {}
```

With all of that said, I'm trying to add instances of DerivedFoo into the control's collection via XAML, but I receive an error that DerivedFoo is not of type IFoo and cannot be used in the generic collection.

I did find a post in a forum that said this was a bug in Silverlight 3 but would be fixed (I am using Silverlight 4).  Is this still a bug or am I going about this incorrectly?

**Update:**
My code is at home and I'm at work so I can't post the actual XAML, but from memory it was along the lines of:

```
<my:Thing>
    <my:Thing.Items>
        <my:DerivedFoo ... />
    </my:Thing.Items>
</my:Thing>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML where you add instances to the collection?

Comment: This should work in Silverlight 4 and its new XAML parser. Can you verify the version?

Comment: Yes, the Silverlight target version for the project is listed as "Silverlight 4".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is...

The CollectionChanged event handler for the generic collection made an improper cast during the Add action.